# Separation components and codereview in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I started read about modules, components, directives. I would like to ask you to check the code and say how I could improve it. The main thing for me is to figure out how I can improve the transparency of this code. I would also like to learn how to split this code into files, and how it should look like the file structure in this case. I heard that I should make one file for components, But how should it look in the inside?

I would really be grateful for help.

because the most important in the life of the programmer is the code review! :)

```
    (function () {
  angular.module('app.navbar', [])
    .component('navbar', {
      bindings: {
        user: '<'
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
        var navbar = this;

        this.$onInit = function () {
          navbar.toggle = false;
        };


        this.activeMenu = function (name, $event) {
          this.blockClosingList($event);
          if (navbar.toggle === true && $scope.name == name) {
            navbar.toggle = !navbar.toggle;
          }
          else if (navbar.toggle === false) {
            navbar.toggle = !navbar.toggle;
          }
          $scope.name = name;
        }


        this.blockClosingList = function ($event) {
          $event.stopPropagation();
        }

      },
      controllerAs: 'navbar',
      template: `

      /////// MENU LEFT SIDE ///////

               <div class="main-navbar">
    <div class="menu-left">
      <div class="btns">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left btn__glyph"></span>
        <span class="btn--name">Tablice</span>
      </div>
      <div class="btns navbar__search">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar__logo">
      <span class="navbar--logo">Tasker</span>
    </div>


      /////// MENU RIGHT SIDE ///////

      <div class="menu-right">
      <a href="#" ng-click="navbar.activeMenu('Create', $event);">
        <div class="btns">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </div>
      </a>


    <!-- MENU CREATE -->
    <div class="menu menu--create" ng-click="navbar.blockClosingList($event)" ng-class="{active : name === 'Create' && navbar.toggle === true}">
      <!--<a href="#" ng-click="navbar.activeMenu('Create', $event);">close</a>-->
     <menu-create></menu-create>
    </div>
    <!---->

<!--MENU CREATE BOARD-->
    <div class="menu cb__menu-coordinate menu--create-board" ng-click="navbar.blockClosingList($event)" ng-class="{active : name === 'menuCreateBoard' && navbar.toggle === true}">
      <span class="settings-menu__header-title">Utwórz Tablicę</span>
       <div class="menu__wrapper--create-board center-block">
        <menu-create-board></menu-create-board>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!---->


    <a href="#" ng-click="navbar.activeMenu('Notice', $event);">
      <div class="btns">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
      </div>
    </a>


<!--NOTIFICATIONS-->
    <div class="menu menu--notice" ng-click="navbar.blockClosingList($event)" ng-class="{active : name === 'Notice' && navbar.toggle === true}">
     <notifications></notifications>
    </div>
    <!---->


    <a href="#" ng-click="navbar.activeMenu('Profile', $event);">
      <div class="btn__circle">
        <span class="btn--circle">B</span>
      </div>
    </a>


<!--MENU PROFILE -->
      <div class="menu menu--avatar" ng-click="navbar.blockClosingList($event)" ng-class="{active : name === 'Profile' && navbar.toggle === true}">
        <profile-menu></profile-menu>
      </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
            `
    })
    .component('profileMenu', {
      require: {
        parent: '^navbar'
      },
      template: `
     <!--<a href="#" ng-click="navbar.activeMenu('Profile', $event);">close</a>-->
      <span class="settings-menu__header-title">
       {{$ctrl.parent.user.username}} {{$ctrl.parent.user.role}}    
      </span>

      <ul class="menu__avatar--list">
          <li>
            <a href="/{{$ctrl.parent.user.username}}">Profil </a>
          </li>

         <li>
           <a href="/{{$ctrl.parent.user.username}}">
         Karty</a>
          </li>

         <li>
           <a href="/{{$ctrl.parent.user.username}}">
         Ustawienia</a>
          </li>

        <li>
          <a href="/logout">
          Wyloguj</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
          `
    })
    .component('notifications', {
      require: {
        parent: '^navbar'
      },
      template: `
      <!--<a href="#" ng-click="navbar.activeMenu('Notice', $event);">close</a>-->
      <span class="settings-menu__header-title">Powiadomienia</span>

      <div class="menu__field--placeholder">
        <span>Brak powiadomień</span>
      </div>
          `
    })

    .component('menuCreateBoard', {
      require: {
        parent: '^navbar'
      },
      template: `
      <form>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="">Tytuł</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="">Zespół</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
         </div>
         <span class="bottom--create-board">Ta tablica będzie Prywatna. Zmień</span> 
         <button class="btn btn-success">Utwórz</button>
       </form> 
          `
    })

    .component('menuCreate', {
      require: {
        parent: '^navbar'
      },
      template: `
 <span class="settings-menu__header-title">Utwórz</span>
      <ul class="menu__create--list">
        <li>
          <a href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.parent.activeMenu('menuCreateBoard', $event);">
            <div class="menu__wrapper-create">
              <span class="menu-create__heading">Utwórz tablicę</span>
              <span class="menu-create__desc">Tablica składa się z kart uporządkowanych w listach. Użyj jej do zarządzania projektami, śledzenia informacji i organizowania wszystkiego.</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="menu__wrapper-create">
              <span class="menu-create__heading">Utwórz zespół</span>
              <span class="menu-create__desc">Zespół składa się z ludzi i tablic. Organizuj z jego pomocą firmę, swoją drugą pracę, plany dla rodziny i spotkania z przyjaciółmi.</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
          `
    })
})();
```

https://gist.github.com/Turqus/2a791c6b86adfc8b6732711eaec2e23d

in main app:

```
var App = angular.module('TodoListApp', ['dndLists', 'app.navbar']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would advise you to go here and learn how to use webpack:
https://webpack.github.io/

After you learn how to bundle your files, you should separate templates out of your js files and use templateUrl to load template - you can webpack template loader - works very good.

Then to improve it even further you can learn to use javascript export (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) functionality and separate your code in files.

I like the following directory structure (for example you could use `navbar` instead of `my-component-name`):

> /my-component-name - directory
>
> my-component-name.component.js - contains my component bindings and templateUrls, also here we import controller for that particular component.
>
> my-component-name.controller.js - sets up controller for component
>
> my-component-name.html - template
>
> my-component-name.scss/less - less/sass file containing isolated styles for that particular component - wrapped in my-component-name {...}
>
> index.js - contains all code put together declaration of angular module, all imports (component,services, directives) and dependencies.

index.js example (you can name it navbar-module.js):

```
import NavbarComponent from './navbar.component'; // <- here you import component

const NavbarModule = angular
  .module('navbar', [])
  .component('navbar', NavbarComponent) // <- here you define your component
  .name;
export default NavbarModule;
```

navbar.component.js example:

```
import templateUrl from './navbar.html';
import controller from './navbar.controller.js'

const NavbarComponent = {
  bindings: {
    user: '<'
  },
  templateUrl, // just a shorthand for writing templateUrl: templateUrl
  controller,   // same as above
}
export default NavbarComponent;
```

and finally navbar.controller.js:

```
class NavbarController {
    constructor($scope, $timeout) {
      this.$scope = $scope; 
      this.$timeout = $timeout;
    }

    $onInit() {
      // set up your on init code here
      this.toggle = true;
    }

    // set up your functions on controller - they will behave same and you will be able to access them via $ctrl.activeMenu() or $ctrl.blockClosingList() in your templates
    activeMenu (name, $event) {
          this.blockClosingList($event);
          if (this.toggle === true && this.$scope.name == name) {
            this.toggle = !this.toggle;
          }
          else if (this.toggle === false) {
            this.toggle = !this.toggle;
          }

          this.$scope.name = name;
        }


    blockClosingList($event) {
       $event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

NavbarController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout']; // inject here and put $scope parameter in your constructor
export default NavbarController;
```

navbar.html - just use your html code it should work fine.

If you need to create some inner functions and keep access to this (controller) you can use arrow functions instead of `function (param) {...}` just use `(param)=>{...}` and inside brackets you will have scope of your controller.

One more thing - isolate your components as much as you can and try to communicate to parent components via $emit/$broadcasts instead of requiring parent component like in your example.

**Keep in mind what I wrote above is in no way tested and most likely has bugs.**

De facto best read about component based architecture in AngularJS can be found here, Todd Motto's styleguide:

https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: hey i have read about using broadcast / emit And I learned that this is a bad technique in case the project is bigger , I heard it's best to use a pattern observer. What do you think? I should learn about this observer pattern or Write using broadcast / emit ???:P

Comment: It all depends what you are trying to do, but I guess that will keep your app tightly coupled which might work better for something but it might be harder to reuse components - if you isolate them it's easier to reuse components as they won't depend on parent components and you won't have one point of delegating everything as in observer pattern which might make your main controller very big (I'm talking from experience since I have an app on my work using observable pattern).

Comment: my English is not good, with answer i suggests that u prefer me to use broadcast / emit then yes?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer before, I prefer that approach and also avoid two way binding. All of this will help you when you move to Angular 2/4 and read that toddmotto's guide that will help a lot as well.

Comment: Ok thanks I have few questions, In ur example I saw "class NavbarController {
    constructor($scope, $timeout) {
      this.$scope = $scope; 
      this.$timeout = $timeout;
    }"     I did not use it till this time, I should use it in my components???

Comment: That was just an example of one way you could do injection to class.

Comment: Ok can u tell me what is differences between $oninit and constructor? I should all parameters have in $oninit and constructor is for only  download files with services yes? can u explain me it please?

Comment: We're getting this comment thread too big, you should read that guide I showed you there is lot of information in there. And to answer your question, yes - use constructor to declare variables of class injections and $onInit is same as you had it in your app - use it to initialize variables.